# QT C++ 5 QTableView Mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, qt5

Есть QTableView в него выгружается таблица из локальной бд, она в кодировке utf-8. При выгрузке, русские символы меняются на символ знака вопроса. Как это исправить?

Comment: покажите код модели или хотя бы как выгружается, если идет конверсия через строки, то обязательно должно быть QString::fromUtf8(...)

Comment: заголовочный файл:
    QSqlDatabase database;
    QSqlQueryModel *querymodel;


main:
/*здесь подключение к бд, а дальше запрос, в str таблица*/
querymodel->setQuery("SELECT * FROM " + str);

ui->tableView->setModel(querymodel);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

querymodel->setQuery("Set names utf8");

Answer (score 0):

Возможное решение:

в main.cpp, сразу после создания экземпляра QApplication добавить строку

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForLocale());
```

Comment: именно так ругается, а если оставить QTextCodec::codecForLocale(); то ничего не меняется